# Write value from a json array to javascript variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, json

How can i make make a variable in a javascript and give it a value from an json array?

The array is sent from a php script and looks like this:

```
php

$stat = array("v1" => "$v1", "v2" => "$v2", "v3" => "$v3",
"v4" => "$v4", "v5" => "$v5", "pump" => "$pump", "flow" => "$flow");
echo json_encode(($stat));

html/javascript

$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function(){
$.getJSON('statusdata.php',function(data) {
$.each(data, function(key, val) {

// I try to do something like this..
var v1 = key[1];
var v2 = key[2];
and so on..
```

Then i want to use a variable to alert a popup-window with some kind of warning.

Someting like:

```
if (v1 == 1){
run the popup function!
}
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: It seems like you don't know how to access object properties / array elements. I recommend to read the MDN JavaScript guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects. Maybe you also have to read about how `$.each` works: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/. FYI, `data` will be an object, so `key` will be the name of the property (e.g. `'v1'`, `'pump'`) and `val` will be the value of that property.

Answer (score 0):

You're using $.each wrong. If you're going to be assigning from data to a set up regular variables you need to do them all individually, not inside a loop.

```
$.getJSON('statusdata.php',function(data) {
  v1 = data["v1"];
  v2 = data["v2"];
}
```